# Angular 7: add comment and get x, y coordinate from selected point on image

Tags: css, angular, html

In my Angular 7 app I would like to have a canvas with the image. When I click on the canvas I will get the x, y coordinates of the point on the image and I should be able to add comment for that particular selected area.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi @NagaSaiA, I'm very new in this kind of UI development so don't have any idea that in which direction i should move to implement it. It will be great if u can suggest something